# Splunk Docker instace Search not executed due to minimum free disk space

Tags: docker, splunk

I have a splunk Docker instance running on my local Mac Book. But the search function in the application is failing.

> Search not executed: The minimum free disk space (5000MB)

I can't cleanup harddisk space much.

What is the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: it needs more space (at least 5000MB (5GB) free)

Answer (score 4):

from [Splunk forum](https://%20https://community.splunk.com/t5/Monitoring-Splunk/How-to-resolve-this-error-The-minimum-free-disk-space-5000MB/m-p/351154)

> Best answer: redo your search head so that /opt/splunk/var is in its own disk volume so that nothing else can take up this space. Some people even go so var as to put /opt/splunk/var/run/dispatch into its own volume.

> The next best answer: add more disk space to to the volume that contains the dispatch directory.

> OK answer: Reduce the TTL for search artifacts so things auto-purge more quickly as described here: https://www.splunk.com/blog/2012/09/12/how-long-does-my-search-live-default-search-ttl.html

> The WORST answer: reduce this quota in Settings -> Server settings -> General settings -> Pause indexing if free disk space (in MB) falls below.

Comment: I used the worst approach for fixing it temporarily. I changed seting from 5000 MB to 500 MB and it solved my issue for now.